# Understanding tension principles in a 2 pulley system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image]Trying to understand tensions in a 2 pulley rope system, where M1>M2. Is it true that T1>T2>T3?

Comment: You'll have to show us what $T_1$, $T_2$, etc. represent. Which pulleys are which?

Comment: The three tensions.

Answer (score 1):

If pulleys are not weightless and maybe rope is not weightless.
Weight $Q_1=m_1 g$ accelerates whole setup. Tension $T_1$ is responsible for acclereating two pulleys, rope and mass $m_2$, $T_2$ accelerates one pulley less to the same acceleration, so that it is lower. By the same reason $T_3$ is lower than $T_2$.